# spring how to stop a bean value being to modified in BeanPostProcessor

Tags: java, spring

My Bean is

```xml
<bean class="org.process.EmployeeBeanPostProcessor"/>
<bean id="address" class="org.beans.employee.Address" >
    <property name="id" value="1" />
    <property name="city" value="City123" />
    <property name="state" value="State123" />
</bean>
```

And My `PostProcess` is

```java
public class EmployeeBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor//, InstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessor
{

  @Override
  public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
        throws BeansException
  {
    System.out.println("Before for the bean " + beanName);
    if (bean instanceof Address)
    {
      ((Address) bean).setCity("New City at Before");
    }
    return bean;
  }

  @Override
  public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
        throws BeansException
  {
    System.out.println("After for the bean " + beanName);
    if (bean instanceof Address)
    {
      ((Address) bean).setCity("New City at After");
    }
    return bean;
  }

}
```

So finally city have a value "New City at After"

Now I Don't want my address bean should be modified in post processor.
Please let me know how to do it.

Comment: Well, simply don't write a post processor that modifies it. What are you trying to achieve? What is the concrete problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: Definitively I am not going to write it,Let me try to explain why I want this.Suppose this is a apart of a framework code and I don't want other developers to modified some sensitive value set to that bean's property.

Comment: If the developers want to shoot themselves in the foot by modifying data that they shouldn't modify, there is no way you can prevent them to do that. Even if your Address class is immutable, they can still use reflection to modify its field values if they want. As long as they have access to the classes, they do whatever they want with them.

Comment: Thanks JB Nizet, for some quick response.I was also guessing, same no way we can stop it, but just for some curiosity checking.Looks like  there is now way :-(

Comment: Use comments to explain the value should not be modified.